# How to change Sitecore Horizon mobile/tablet view from Apple (iphone 7/iPad) to Android

Tags: mobile, horizon

I'm trying to change the Sitecore Horizon mobile and tablet view from Apple to Android. Also, I need a few clarifications.

1. How can we change the default from Apple to Android?
2. Why is the Horizon default view an older version of the iPhone (iPhone 7)?
3. Can we change it to the latest version of the iPhone?
4. If it is a generic view for mobile, is it not better to rename it to simply "mobile" and "tablet"?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Customizing Horizon should be possible as from version 2.. (so not now). But whether you will be able to change those settings is not known. You should post these ideas on the Sitecore feedback program - subscribe here: https://www.sitecore.com/company/contact-us/product-feedback
2. That's a question for the product team
3. See 1...
4. The view is not generic as they do send a user agent and it might affect your view (depending on your solution). I guess in most cases you could call it generic but it does make sense to indicate the user agent.